# Can't install hsdev with cabal

Tags: haskell, module, cabal, hsdev

I'm on Arch, and I'm trying to install `hsdev` with cabal (`cabal install hsdev`), but when it starts compiling and it gets to compiling `HsDev.Tools.GhcMod` I get following message :

```
[46 of 58] Compiling HsDev.Tools.GhcMod ( src/HsDev/Tools/GhcMod.hs, dist/build/HsDev/Tools/GhcMod.o )

src/HsDev/Tools/GhcMod.hs:64:54:
    ‘GhcMod.ghcUserOptions’ is not a (visible) constructor field name

src/HsDev/Tools/GhcMod.hs:73:34:
    ‘GhcMod.detailed’ is not a (visible) constructor field name

src/HsDev/Tools/GhcMod.hs:73:58:
    ‘GhcMod.qualified’ is not a (visible) constructor field name

src/HsDev/Tools/GhcMod.hs:73:83:
    ‘GhcMod.ghcUserOptions’ is not a (visible) constructor field name

src/HsDev/Tools/GhcMod.hs:118:38:
    ‘GhcMod.ghcUserOptions’ is not a (visible) constructor field name

src/HsDev/Tools/GhcMod.hs:176:58:
    ‘GhcMod.ghcUserOptions’ is not a (visible) constructor field name

src/HsDev/Tools/GhcMod.hs:221:32:
    ‘GhcMod.ghcUserOptions’ is not a (visible) constructor field name

src/HsDev/Tools/GhcMod.hs:228:32:
    ‘GhcMod.hlintOpts’ is not a (visible) constructor field name
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
hsdev-0.1.4.3 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: What version of GHC are you using? And did you try compiling it in a sandbox?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I have figured it out. Latest version of ghc-mod is not compatible with hsdev, so I had to add constraint for it:

```
ghc-mod >= 5.3.0.0 && < 5.4.0.0
```